# BizTalk JSON encoder pipeline generating incorrect JSON object from XSD

Tags: json, biztalk, pipeline, encoder, biztalk-2016

I am using BizTalk pipeline with JSON encoder to convert XML to JSON .
I have created the XSD but the JSON generated has #text instead of just a value for my elements.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"      elementFormDefault="unqualified"     targetNamespace="http://BookingEngine.Schemas.JSONSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="affiliate_reference_id" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="hold" type="xs:boolean" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="rooms">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="email" type="xs:string" />

        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="payments">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="type" type="xs:string" />

        </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="affiliate_metadata" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

is converted to the following JSON

```
{
  "affiliate_reference_id": {
    "#text": "4480"
  },
  "hold": {
    "#text": "false"
  },
  "rooms": [
    {
      "email": "john@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "payments": [
    {
      "type": "customer_card"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected results would be

```
{
  "affiliate_reference_id": "4480",
  "hold":  "false",
  "rooms": [
    {
      "email": "john@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "payments": [
    {
      "type": "customer_card"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why the #text is popping up and how to remove it?
What do I need to change in my XSD schema?

Comment: Which version of BizTalk?  I just tried it with BizTalk 2013 R2 and the output is as you expected.

Comment: That behaviour is similar to when you have attributes on elements see my blog post https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/biztalk-json-decoder-representation-of-xml-attributes/

Comment: @Dijkgraaf 2016

Comment: @Dijkgraaf so how do propose I solve this ? Create a custom pipeline ? Or change the schema so that #text is not created ?

Comment: Are you using BizTalk Standard or Enterprise?  If Enterprise have you installed the Feature Packs. As part of Feature Pack 2 supports version 10.0.3 of Newtonsoft.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/configure-the-feature-pack#feature-pack-2-updates   Not sure what change you could do to the schema to stop it happening, as I cannot reproduce it in 2013 R2.  I'll see if I can get access to a BizTalk 2016 environment, but that might not be until the new year

Comment: @Dijkgraaf enterprise . Guess I’ll have to make a custom pipeline and do the conversion myself

Comment: Be aware, that is not the correct JSON Boolean format.  >"false"< is a string, not a bool to JSON.  >false< is the correct format.

Comment: @Johns-305  True enough, when I use the schema from the OP in BizTalk 2013 R2, the true or false are without quotes. As well as the affliliate_reference_id, no quotes as it is a numeric value

Answer (score 1):

‪I've the same result in c# when using Newtonsoft. The #text nodes are added when they have a different namespace than the root-namespace because in JSON it becomes an object with a text and a attribute namespace. ‬

Comment: Ahhh makes sense.... made a custom pipeline and removed all namespaces and it works now..... guess i could of just matched the namespaces correctly.

Comment: @vaughn  Give that a go and if that works, post it as the answer.  However you XSD didn't have two namespaces.  Did you payload have a different namespace for some of the elements?   Yes, that can cause havoc with the JSON encoder.

Answer (score 1):

I created a pipeline with a JSON encoder and had this same issue.

The secret is you need to add an XML encoder before the JSON encoder in your pipeline.  Yes, it's odd.

Create a schema with the correct data types for the JSON results you want. Add that schema to the XML encoder document schema property. The schema allows you to control how the JSON encoder works.

Note: XML requires a single root node but JSON does not. In your JSON assembly schema create a root node with any name you like. In the JSON encoder there's a check box to remove the root node enclosing the payload.

Javascript data types are not the same as XML (such as dates) so some translation may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom biztalk pipeline and used json newton soft nuget package .